# In Postgres transaction if Command.ExecuteNonQuery successes, can commit fails?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am using transaction to execute the query as sample code as below :

```
private void CallStoredProcedure(string storedProcedureName, string transferObject, int changeSetId)
{
try
{
using (var conn = m_Connection)
{
using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
try
{
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(storedProcedureName, m_Connection))
{
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DataBaseConstants.TransferObjectParameterName, transferObject);                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DataBaseConstants.ChangeSetId, changeSetId);
command.Transaction = tran;
lock (m_LockObject)
{
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
tran.Commit();                                                           
}
}
catch (NpgsqlException ex)
{
tran.Rollback();
}
}
}
}
catch (NpgsqlException e)
{
               
}
}
```

If command.ExecuteNonQuery() succeed can there may be chances of commit fails ?

I want to know the scenarios when the commit fails.

Comment: Please format your code. Simplest thing why commit fails would be a connection loss. But there are multiple other ways why commit may fail depending on the database type its used feature set like different type of Transaction Isolation and so on. There isn't something like a complete list of why it may fail. But many of the potential long list of reasons might be in the obscure region you simply can't handle well you can just notice/log it when commiting fails.

Comment: Other than Connection loss, Is there any major thing that makes the Commit failure.